# Elasticsearch more than one should, must and combined

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I learning Elasticsearch, but i don't know how combine should and must. I need one field with some value and other field with several values, this condition can repeat several times. For example,

```
(Field1 == 1 and (Field2 == "a" or Field2 == "b" )) or
(Field1 == 2 and (Field2 == "c" or Field2 == "d" )) or
(Field1 == 3 and (Field2 == "a" or Field2 == "c" )) .... etc
```

I try many ways, but i can't use bool, must o should at same level. For example,

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must":  [
                                { "term": { "Field1": 1 } },
                                {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "should": [
                                            { "terms": { "Field2" : [ "a", "b" ] } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                                { "term": { "Field1": 2 } },
                                {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "should": [
                                            { "terms": { "Field2" : [ "c", "d" ] } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    },
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                                { "term": { "Field1": 2 } },
                                {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "should": [
                                            { "terms": { "Field2" : [ "a", "c" ] } }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I really need for NEST, but i wanna start with this.

Comment: Take a look at the docs on writing queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-queries.html and writing bool queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html

Comment: thanks, with those post, i converted the answer to NEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "field1": 1
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "field2": [
                          "a",
                          "b"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "field1": 2
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "field2": [
                          "c",
                          "d"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "field1": 3
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "terms": {
                        "field2": [
                          "a",
                          "c"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you want `a OR b OR c` where `a`, `b`, `c` represent any type of query then this is expressed in elastic query as:

```
{
  "bool": {
    "should": [
      {
        a
      },
      {
        b
      },
      {
        c
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Replace `a`, `b`, `c` with exact queries.